# android- can't write in a map in an anonymous class

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using an interface to get the read a value from the database , in a `Map` and i want to put some information on another `Map` in an anonymous class,but i can't write in the `Map` ,how can write in a Map and can I declare a map without having to implement all the methods ?

```
public void addFriend(String UserId, final String email)
    {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        DatabaseReference user = mDatabase.child(UserId);
        final DatabaseReference friendlist = user.child("contact");
        checkUser(email, new ICheckUserListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final Map value) {
            friendlist.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Map<String, String> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    if(map==null&&value!=null)
                    {
                        map= new Map<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public int size() {
                                return 0;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean isEmpty() {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String get(Object key) {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String put(String key, String value) {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String remove(Object key) {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void putAll(@NonNull Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void clear() {

                            }

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Set<String> keySet() {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Collection<String> values() {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Set<Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public int hashCode() {
                                return 0;
                            }
                        };
                        Log.w(TAG,"methods addFriend Value Val"+value.get("email"));
                        Log.w(TAG,"methods addFriend Value "+value.get("username"));
                        // i can see Value values
                        map.put("email",""+email.toString().trim());
                        map.put("username",""+value.get("username").toString().trim());
                        Log.w(TAG,"methods addFriend Map :"+map.get("email"));
                        // here i can't get the map values
                       friendlist.setValue(map);
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` is a interface, you need some implementation, you probably want a `HashMap`

```
map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can see the different implementing classes in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)